# Create a war file from a mercurial repository with maven

Tags: maven-2, mercurial

I have a mercurial repository on my server.
I want to create a script to deploy the project as a war file to a tomcat server.
Is it possible to tell maven to get the latest revision of my project from the repository
and create a war file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Maven SCM plugin](http://maven.apache.org/scm/plugins/index.html), which has suport for multiple version control systems [including Mercurial](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SCM/SCM+Matrix).